# Combining 2 physical VLAN ports to send over single cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vlan

My ISP supplied us with a ONT modem, with 2 physical LAN ports; one for internet, one for IPTV.

PORT 1 - Route Mode, 1_INTERNET_R_VID_881, NAT, Internet, VLAN 881, PPPoE

PORT 2 - Bridge Mode, 2_OTHER_R_VIS_111, no NAT, IPTV, VLAN 111, DHCP

I'd like to send both VLANs over to another area.  Can I somehow combine both of them into on one physical cable, on one side, and split them back up at the other side?

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible by means available for a consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s quite easy, too. The “combined signal” is achievable with VLAN trunking. It works by sending the VLAN ID as a header in the Ethernet packet. On Linux, this would result in two virtual interfaces `eth0.0` and `eth0.1` for VLANs 0 and 1 on `eth0`. You can then bridge these interfaces to the physical interfaces where the modem is connected to.

If you don’t want to run two computers, a (smart) managed switch might be enough. You just need to check whether they can do VLAN trunking (and not only port-based VLANs).

(Be aware though: Some low-cost smart managed switches do not have a web interface and can only be set up using a Windows program.)

Comment: Just to clarify, you would 2 VLAN devices (switches or computers) - one to "combine" the VLANs and the other to "split" them back apart at the other end.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Unless of course devices at the other end support multiple VLANs. Windows doesn’t, for example.